# String tokenizer and Scanner java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, stringtokenizer

I have a large text file which I want to separate into different strings using the delimiter !- (Each string is multiple lines).

I then want to discard all the other strings that do not contain:

```
===========  ALL OBJECTS IN CLASS: FENESTRATIONSURFACE:DETAILED ===========
```

So far I've got this and its not outputting anything (it complies but no output to console).I'm new to programming and I'm not making much progress after researching this for sometime so any suggestions or pointers would be most appreciated thanks!

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/Anton/Pictures/1 x geotransform0.5m shading.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(scan.nextLine(),"!-");
            if(st.equals("   ===========  ALL OBJECTS IN CLASS: FENESTRATIONSURFACE:DETAILED ===========")) {
                System.out.print(st);
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider reading the java doc page to `StringTokenizer`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

### There two different problems in your code:

1. Because your desired strings are more than one line out of a file, you first have to add them up (into a `String`) and then work with it via `StringTokenizer` to separate again.
2. You have to compare the `StringTokenizer.nextToken()` to your check `String` not the whole `StringTokenizer`. `StringTokenizer.nextToken()` then gives you the next String separated through `!-`.

### The following code should work:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("C:/Users/Anton/Pictures/1 x geotransform0.5m shading.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    //Scanning
    //first scan the whole file into a string (because a sting can have more than one line)
    String temp = "";
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        temp = scan.nextLine();
    }
    //now add the string to tokeinzer
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(temp,"!-");
    //now give output
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    String temp2 = st.nextToken();
        if(temp2.equals("   ===========  ALL OBJECTS IN CLASS: FENESTRATIONSURFACE:DETAILED ===========")) {
            System.out.print(temp2);
        }
    }
    scan.close();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Robert firstly thanks for your answer this partially works the main thing is that you forgot to put
         temp = temp + scan.nextLine() to update the value of temp in the first while loop. Once this is fixed it only outputs "   ===========  ALL OBJECTS IN CLASS: FENESTRATIONSURFACE:DETAILED ==========="  What I want to do is to output the token that CONTAINS this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

remove the if condition and add the below while condition

```
 while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
                        System.out.println(st.nextElement());
                    }
```

because stringtokenizer splits the text based on token. so your if never becomes true.

Answer (score 0):

try this...........

```
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(scan.nextLine(),"!-");
                while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                    String stt = st.nextElement().toString();
                    if(stt.equals("===========  ALL OBJECTS IN CLASS: FENESTRATIONSURFACE:DETAILED ===========")) {
                        System.out.print(stt);
                    }
                }
            }
```

you comparing string with stringtokenizer object not value....